# Preventing repeated sequences in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, constraints, shuffle

I have a 192 x 3 matrix, order(192 x 3):

order(:, 1) and order(:, 2) both contain repeating values of 1 - 16, and order(:, 3) contains repeating values of 1 and 2. I need to shuffle the matrix, while preventing any repeats of more than three of the same value in the last column, so order(:, 3) should never show more than 3 repeats of 1 or 2.

This is what I have, which worked for a smaller version of the matrix just fine, but seems to get stuck with a slightly larger matrix:

```
not_good = true;

while not_good

    not_good = false;

    order = Shuffle(order);

    % returns an array of 1s and 0s indexing the position of the values for 1 and 2
    R1 = order(:, 3) == 1;
    R2 = order(:, 3) == 2;

    % checks for repeats, returns 1 if repeats are present
    rep_test1 = any(diff([1; find(R1)])>3);
    rep_test2 = any(diff([1; find(R2)])>3);

    if rep_test1 > 0 || rep_test2 > 0
        not_good = true;
    end
end
```

Any comments much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1) In some cases, it is impossible. For instance, when all order(:,3) are equal. 2) Do you want the shuffle to be random? 3) Is it a homework?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, not homework, an experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you already found an arrangement that fulfills your conditions. But it should be possible to construct such an arrangement.

I would make the shuffling with [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

Pseudocode would be:

```
function shuffled = shuffle(orig)
for i=1:numShuffles
  [i1,i2] = randomIndices;
  tmp = shuffled with permuted lines i1 and i2 
  test if matrix is still valid
  if valid shuffled=tmp;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info re. rejection sampling!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any low-level control over how the `Shuffle` function is implemented, it's most efficient to make a problem-specific implementation thereof. E.g., make a version that rejects unsolvable problems right away, and rejects any new addition to the output matrix inside the loop if it's equal to the two entries above it.

But assuming you don't have this level of control, than I have to agree with @Oli. There is no inherent flaw to your code, it just lacks checks to see if the problem is at all solvable or not.

It does have a major drawback though. For example, if

```
order(:,3).' = [1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...]
```

the chances of getting (more than) three consecutive ones after a `Shuffle` will be quite large. This means the loop will have to run for a large number of times before it gives any result. Unfortunately, if the problem is solvable but just "hard to solve" as in this case, there's little you can do but wait.